# How to set horizontal scroll menu bar

Tags: android

friend's,
  I have task to set menus in horizontal scrolling with images at two ends to show availability of menus. I did it by using gallery view, but i need to place an seperator (Vertical Line) between menus,i can't able to get the seperator in between the gallery.
How can i get it.

i need the view below

```
        ----------------------------------------
         <   menu1     |  menu2  |   menu3   >
       -----------------------------------------
```

just refer CBSNews application if u have.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the idea is to include the separator into the layout for the gallery items, e.g:

```
<View android:id="@+id/separator" android:background="#000" 
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp" android:layout_marginRight="15sp" 
    android:layout_width="3sp" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></View>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/separator" 
    android:layout_height="80dip" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerInside"></ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in your SimpleAdapter-derived class, hide the separator for the item with position 0:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        View separator = view.findViewById(R.id.separator);
        if ( separator != null)
            separator.setVisibility(position == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        return view;
    }
```

Set the gallery spacing such that it corresponds nicely with the margins set to the separator in the layout.